# Let n be an integer. If n is the square of the integer m, then n's rightmost digit is 0, 1, 4, 5, 6, or 9.

Tags: logic

Here is a theorem about integers: "Let n be an integer. If n is the square of the integer m, then n's rightmost digit is 0, 1, 4, 5, 6, or 9."

A) Does the theorem imply that no integer with rightmost digit equal to 2 can be the square of another integer? explain.

B)The integer 31 is not the square of an integer. Explain why this does not contradict the theorem.

pretty lost on this would be great if i could get some help thanks.

Comment: What square numbers do you know? What are the last digits of those?

Comment: Notice that $9^2=81$.  $19^2= 10^2+2(10)(9)+9^2=361$

Answer (score 2):

A) Yes. This is because every number can be expressed as $a·10+b$, being $b$ the rightmost digit, so $0 \leq b \leq 9$.

Then, $(a·10+b)^2= 100a^2+20ab+b^2= 10(10a^2+2ab)+b^2$

As $10$ divides $10(10a^2+2ab)$, we can just consider $b^2$ for the last digit.

We then can just consider cases, as $0 \leq b \leq 9$.

$0^2=0$, $1^2=1$, $2^2=4$, $3^2=9$, $4^2=16$, $5^2=25$, $6^2=36$, $7^2=49$, $8^2=64$, $9^2=81$

And the only last digits here are 0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 9.

B) This is more of a logic question.

The theorem says that the number being a square implies that its last digit is $0, 1, 4, 5, 6$ or $9$.

However, it doesn't say that its last digit being one of those implies it being a square.

More generally, $P \Longrightarrow Q$ and $Q \Longrightarrow P$ are not the same thing.

Imagine your teacher says that whoever fails the next exam fails the term. Failing the exam implies failing the term. However, failing the term doesn't imply that you failed the exam. There are many more reasons why you might fail the term, like having failed every other exam.

Comment: You don't actually have to prove the theorem to answer either of the questions.  (Though this is a nice proof.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple case of if something is true, then it follows that another thing is true.  However, the converse does not always apply.  For example, if all lions are animals, it does not mean that all animals are lions. This is why B is not true.

The contra-positive of a statement is always true.  If all lions are animals, the contrapositive means that if something is not an animal, it is not a lion.  Therefore, if something does not have a digit in the set of numbers given by the theorem, it is not a square number. Explaining why A is true.

Answer (score 0):

we can write m as the (10^n*a+(10^n-1)*b...10^0*k) and  if we define m-k as x 
then we can write m as (x+k) and by squaring it we get x^2+2xk+k^2 and we know x^2 and 2xm>10 so only k^2 effects rightmost digit. and squares of the 1 digit numbers are as follows 0,1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81 so they all end with 0,1,4,5,6,9.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your post.